# Sleep function not behaving like it should in discord.py

Tags: discord, sleep, discord.py

I'm trying to write a temp mute command which mutes the user and then unmutes them after the set time is up however it doesn't seem to be working after the sleep command.

```
import sleep

@client.command()
async def mute(ctx, member : discord.Member, time, *, reason = None):
    muted = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = "Muted")
    await member.add_roles(muted)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Muted!", description= member.mention + " was just muted from the server", color=0x00ff00)
    embedVar.add_field(name="For " + time + " Minutes", value= "With Reason " + reason, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
    wait = time * 60
    time.sleep(wait)
    await member.remove_roles(muted)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Unmuted", description= member.mention + " Is Now Unmuted", color=0x00ff00)
    embedVar.add_field(name="After Waiting", value= time + " Minutes", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Comment: Did you mean `import time`?

Comment: I would also suggest using asyncio sleep. `time.sleep()` will pause the entire bot, not just this command. `import asyncio` and `await asyncio.sleep(time)`

Comment: Thank you very much asyncio fixed it